# XSLT error - "Token Text in state Start would result in an invalid XML document."

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I have an XSLT that is transforming XML from an external application into my own object, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="SimpleObject">
    <NewSimpleObject>
      <NewField1>
        <xsl:value-of select="OldField1"/>
      </NewField1>
      <NewField2>
        <xsl:value-of select="OldField2"/>
      </NewField2>
    </NewSimpleObject>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The incoming XML is really simple, although it has a lot of fields that I am not using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SimpleObject>
  <OldField1>Test</OldField1>
  <OldField2>Value</OldField2>
  <OldField3/>
  <OldField4/>
  <OldField5/>
  <OldField6/>
  <OldField7/>
</SimpleObject>
```

When I try to apply the XSLT in C#, I get the following error:

```
Token Text in state Start would result in an invalid XML document. Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to write an XML fragment.
```

Here is my executing code:

```
    public string ApplyTransform(string xml, string operationName)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;

        var resourceName = GetResourceNameFromOperationName(operationName);

        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
            {
                using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
                {
                    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
                    {
                        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
                        {
                            using (var xslReader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
                            {
                                var compiledTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
                                compiledTransform.Load(xslReader);
                                compiledTransform.Transform(xmlReader, xmlWriter);

                                result = stringWriter.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Please show minimal but complete code to allow us to reproduce the issue, including the C# code. Are you writing to a file or to an XmlWriter?

Comment: The XSLT works fine against the posted input at http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LVt and also does not create a fragment so I don't see why you would get that error. But we need to see the C# code to be able to reproduce, understand and fix the problem.

Comment: Added the C# method.

Comment: As you create your own XmlWriter, you would get such an error if your stylesheet produced a fragment. However, I don't see that happening with the current XML and XSLT as posted. I am not sure what kind of result you want and what you want to fix, if you want to return any result as a string, then consider using an overload of the `Transform` method writing to a TextWriter, passing in your `stringWriter` for that, avoiding the creation of the XmlWriter.

Comment: As an alternative, you can read out the `OutputSettings` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.outputsettings(v=vs.110).aspx from the stylesheet and use them you create your XmlWriter. Then you can look at the result and check why it causes that error.

Comment: I changed the conformace level to "Auto" and the result was weird. It was just input XML but all of the tags went from <tag> to &lt;tag&rt;, Maybe this is a clue?

Comment: Are you sure the input is as posted? Sounds more like some XML escaping the one you have shown as a CDATA section.

Comment: If you check http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LVt/1 where I have changed the input to have your sample escaped as a CDATA section then you will see that the result is the one you say you get, so I think somehow your input is not as described.

Comment: You're right, the input changed when i grabbed it from the text visualizer.

I think something is off with the encoding of the XML that I get from the external web service. When I run it through the XSLT, it adds the following header:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>

Notice that I specified utf-8 at the top. This is in addition to all of the < and > being replaced by &lt; and &gt; respectively.

I can still provide raw input if you think it would help, but since this is likely an encoding issue, I don't think you'll be able to reproduce...

Comment: As for the `encoding="utf-16"` you get in your output, that happens as .NET does that when you serialize to a `StringWriter` as strings in .NET are UTF-16 encoded. As for the original problem, well, if the input has encoded XML then you will need to change the stylesheet or change the processing receiving the response from the web service, it is not an XSLT problem in the latter case.